# Bootstrap image gallery with pagination - strategy advice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, memory, pagination

I'm constructing a web page with a Bootstrap modal form. When the modal form is opened, it displays a grid of images (using Bootstrap 2.3.2 media-grid) that the user can select.

I'd only been testing with a limited number of images, but there will be the potential for users to display up to 1024 images at a time.

It's obviously not a good experience to display a large number of images in a single set, so I've added pagination.

**The question I have is about whether my strategy for obtaining and displaying the images is... sane.**

Hyperlinks to all images are stored in a mySQL database. I retrieve all of the hyperlinks in a single query, returned to the browser as JSON data following an ajax request when the modal form is first opened.

All images are one of two sizes. At my screen size and resolution, about 32 are shown per 'page'.

The content of each page - or everything inside the .media-grid - is added dynamically. Initially only elements for the first page of images are added (within a container div that sits inside the media-grid) as the modal dialog is opened.

When the user clicks another page number, the elements for that page are added.

The elements for the previous page are then detached (Jquery detach()) from the modal dialog, and stored in a global array (or rather, the div containing all images is detached and a reference to it stored in the global array).

When the user returns to a previously visited page, the container div is retrieved from the global array, and appended to the media-grid.

**I'm concerned about memory use and bindings.**

It seems like a bad idea - from a memory perspective - to store a large number of pre-constructed divs containing image elements in the global array. So I'm planning to limit the number to maybe 6 or 8 (I've arrived at that number fairly arbitrarily), clearing out the oldest stored div to make way for a newer one. If a div is not available in the array, but has been previously visited, it would have to be reconstructed.

Still, I don't know whether it's sensible to store all of that in working memory. Would it be better to just recreate each page as it's visited? That seems like a lot of object creation and destruction though.

I have event handlers associated with images in the media-grid to respond to clicks and mouse hovers. I don't do anything to explicitly remove these when I clear a div of image elements (using JQuery empty() on the container div) - does this have implications, or will the garbage collector look after that for me?

I'd be grateful if someone could sanity check my thinking here and suggest whether I should re-formulate my approach. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use AJAX to fetch images for each page?...

Comment: Hey qtgye - do you mean instead of retrieving the hyperlinks for all images in one go, only retrieving hyperlinks for the currently displayed page? Ah, I forgot I can't add line-breaks in comments. This might get messy... That's a fair suggestion, but my concern remains the same: what's the best way to deal with creating and storing individual pages - I'm "caching" previously created pages at present and wondering if this is acceptable from a memory use standpoint. I see working memory jump by about 150MB in Task Manager with 8 stored pages for example

Comment: Equally, creating a page, then just deleting everything on that page when a different page number is selected would cause a lot of memory fragmentation and possibly performance problems I'd have thought (since all page elements would have to be recreated each time the page was viewed). Or perhaps there are other ways of doing this I haven't even conceived of.